# Jquery not passing checkbox values correctly

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am attempting to make interactive checkboxes for my site which display a pop up once you tick a certain value. I have it mostly working however it wont seem to pass the names of the checkboxes to my alert test. It will always display question1 no matter which checkbox I use.

```
<script async  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>


function HasChanged()
{
    if($('.common_question').is(":checked")) 
    {  
        alert($('.common_question').val());
    }
}

</script>
<div id="chkbox" style="width=75%">
<form method="post">
        <fieldset>
                <legend>Select your reason for contact from below.</legend>
                        <h2>Premium Accounts</h2>
                        <input type="checkbox" onchange="HasChanged()" class="common_question" name="questiontype" value="question1" />I want to purchase a premium account<br />
                        <div style="display:none" id="prem1">Answer is here </div>
                        <input type="checkbox" onchange="HasChanged()" class="common_question" name="questiontype" value="question2" />I want to cancel a premium account<br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
        </fieldset>
</form>    
</div>
```

I am stumped as where I am going wrong, I just want the alert to just display the correct checkbox that has been picked.

Comment: both your checkboxes have `common_question` class.....

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) does

> Get the current value of the **first element** in the set of matched
>   elements

It gets the value from the first element in the collection, not neccessarely the one you changed.
You should be using a proper event handler and then access `this`

```
<div id="chkbox" style="width=75%">
  <form method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Select your reason for contact from below.</legend>
      <h2>Premium Accounts</h2>
      <input type="checkbox" class="common_question" name="questiontype" value="question1" />I want to purchase a premium account
      <br />
      <div style="display:none" id="prem1">Answer is here </div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="common_question" name="questiontype" value="question2" />I want to cancel a premium account
      <br />
      <input type="submit" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.common_question').on('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) alert(this.value);
    });
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ux6gyv9a/)